# PHP session variable not passed

Tags: php, session, null

I have 2 pages

**one.php**:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["myvar"] = "Hello World!";
header("Location: http://mysite.com/two.php");
die;

?>
```

**two.php**:

```
<?php

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION["myvar"]); 

?>
```

when it goes to page two it shows NULL instead of Hello World!.

*php v5.3.8*

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? have you checked in 'one.php' the session is being set?

Comment: What happens when you get rid of the `header(); die;` calls, and just access `one.php` and then `two.php` directly?

Comment: And.... did the cookie get set? Check your browser.

Comment: check configuration of your php and server. your code is correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

I just tried your example with php 5.3.8(same version as you) and get

```
string(12) "Hello World!"
```

as output. So what I conclude from this is that your session folder is not writable. Maybe you should read [php - session save path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) and chose another session save path. I guess that's your problem.

And: As all the others said: Turn on error_reporting by `error_reporting(E_ALL);`